# Simplifying Geometric Sum with Summand and Upper Bound both Functions of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, asymptotics, geometric-series

Working with asymptotics, I frequently encounter expressions of the following form in my upper bound:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{f(n)} g(n)^k$$
Almost always, I have trouble simplifying them. An example of something I had to simplify recently:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt n} n^{-k/2} = \frac{1 - n^{-\sqrt{n}/2}}{\sqrt n - 1}$$
I only got the RHS by Wolfram Alpha, but I want to know the step that can get me there. Suppose I start with the standard formula for geometric sum, how would I get to this? In general, what techniques are there to simplifying the geometric sum formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{f(n)} g(n)^k$ form a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). For such sums there is a simple [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series), which in this particular case yields
$$\sum_{k=1}^{f(n)} g(n)^k=g(n)\frac{1-g(n)^{\lfloor f(n)\rfloor}}{1-g(n)\hphantom{{}^{\lfloor f(n)\rfloor}}}.$$
In your example $g(n)=n^{-1/2}=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $f(n)=\sqrt{n}$, so that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt n} n^{-k/2}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1-(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{1-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
=\frac{1-\sqrt{n}^{-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}-1}.$$